# How to fix error with creating bean with name?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to create a Left Outer join in my project using Hibernate and JPA. However, after I setup all my procedures and wrote the code for it to join, it throws this error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements: com.model.AVSApplication.avsMapped
```

I have an idea what it is telling me, but I have tried a work around but it still continues to give me the same error. I don't believe it is an issue with the database side, then I believe it is an issue with either the controller or the Entity section of `AVSApplicationn.class` or `AVSMapped.class`.

**AppRepository:**

```
@Repository
public interface AppRepository extends JpaRepository<AVSMapped, String>{

    @Query("SELECT avs.appcode, avs.acro, avs.appname, mapped.gpStatus " 
            + "FROM avs LEFT JOIN mapped ON avs.appcode = mapped.appcode")
    List<ApplicationDTO> fetchAppDataLeftJoin();

}
```

**JoinQueryService:**

```
public class JoinQueryService {

    @Resource
    private AppRepository appRepository;


    public List<ApplicationDTO> getAppLeftJoin(){
        List<ApplicationDTO> list = appRepository.fetchAppDataLeftJoin();
        list.forEach(l-> System.out.println(l));
        return list;
    }

}
```

**Controller:**

```
@org.springframework.stereotype.Controller
public class AVSController {

        @Autowired
        private JoinQueryService joinQueryService;



      @GetMapping("/dept")
      public ResponseEntity<List<ApplicationDTO>> getAppLeftJoin(){
          return new ResponseEntity<List<ApplicationDTO>>(joinQueryService.getAppLeftJoin(), HttpStatus.OK);
      }
```

**AVSApplication:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "avs")
public class AVSApplication {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "appcode")
    private String appcode;

    @Column(name = "acro")
    private String acro;

    @Column(name = "appname")
    private String appname;


    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "mGpStatus", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    private AVSMapped avsMapped;
```

**AVSMapped:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "mapped")
public class AVSMapped  {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "mAppcode")
    private String mAppcode;

    @Column(name = "mAcro")
    private String mAcro;

    @Column(name = "mAppname")
    private String mAppname;

    @Column(name = "mGpStatus")
    private String mGpStatus;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = AVSApplication.class, mappedBy ="appcode", orphanRemoval = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<AVSApplication> avsApplication;
```

**ApplicationDTO:**

```
public class ApplicationDTO {


    private String dtoAppCode;
    private String dtoAcro;
    private String dtoAppName;
    private String dtoGpStatus;

    //Constructor
    public ApplicationDTO(String dtoAppCode, String dtoAcro, String dtoAppName, String dtoGpStatus) {
        super();
        this.dtoAppCode = dtoAppCode;
        this.dtoAcro = dtoAcro;
        this.dtoAppName = dtoAppName;
        this.dtoGpStatus = dtoGpStatus;
        //this.dtoLastUpdate = dtoLastUpdate;
    }
```

**Updated Error:**

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field joinQueryService in com.controller.AVSController required a bean of type 'com.model.JoinQueryService' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.model.JoinQueryService' in your configuration.
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see the number of issues in the snippet.

`@ManyToMany` mapping in one entity class is not correct. It should be `@ManyToOne`

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "mGpStatus", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
private AVSMapped avsMapped;
```

`JoinQueryService` cannot be autowired in the controller unless you have `@Bean` configuration inplace. Annotate your class with Stereotype annotation

```
@Service
public class JoinQueryService {
     ...
}
```

In `JPA` repository change the Generics type with `Entity` class

```
@Query("SELECT avs.appcode, avs.acro, avs.appname, mapped.gpStatus " 
        + "FROM avs LEFT JOIN mapped ON avs.appcode = mapped.appcode")
List<AVSMapped> fetchAppDataLeftJoin();
```

Comment: Ok, I am applying your suggestions but what do you mean change the Generics type?

Comment: Change `List<ApplicationDTO>` to `List<AVSMapped>`

Comment: So I made the adjustments but it gives me a new error. I made an update to the original question to add the new error. I believe it is because once I changed the entity from ```ApplicationDTO``` to ```AVSMapped``` somehow it was related properly. Nah sure if I am correct

Comment: @kane_004 Annotate JoinQueryService class with Spring's `@Service`

Comment: I don't know if I am stupid or what but I keep getting an error. Now I get  this error ```Error creating bean with name 'joinQueryService': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.db.AppRepository.fetchAppDataLeftJoin()!```

Comment: @Giovinda Sakhare Once I changed it from ```ApplicationDTO``` to ```AVSMapped``` I had to tweak the other classes and now nothing works. lol I guess I got to keep researching